# SQL to display and order by converted date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to use SQL to display a date in a new format e.g. dd-mm-yyyy and then sort by converted the date?

I tried something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date Depart], 105) AS [Date Depart]
FROM FLIGHT
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date Depart], 105) DESC
```

It is not working on MS SQL Server. It it still sort by VARCHAR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order by the unconverted date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date Depart], 105) AS [Date Departed]
  FROM FLIGHT
 ORDER BY [Date Depart] DESC
```

You can still order by the actual date field, even if you're selecting the date converted into a different format in your select list.

Also named the column [Date Departed] so that the ORDER BY clause would not think I was referring to the column alias as opposed to the actual field name. The ORDER BY clause will think you are referring to columns aliases BEFORE referring to actual field names, when applicable. So if you order by a column that you give an alias which happens to be the same name as an actual field on the table, it will order by the result column first, not the actual field on the table.

You can use this if you absolutely want to use [Date Depart] as the column name:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date Depart], 105) AS [Date Depart]
  FROM FLIGHT
 ORDER BY cast([Date Depart] as date) desc
```

It converts the result column back to a date.

Comment: I have tried and it is not working on SQL Server 2012. It can work if I change the ... AS [Date Depart] to something else. Not sure if this is a bug or what but I need to use back the original column name for the SQL.

Comment: @Withhelds see my edit, yes the column aliases take precedence over actual field names in the ORDER BY

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Is it possible if I would like to use back the same column name?

Comment: @Withhelds you can convert the date to yy/mm/dd in the order by clause. see my edit.

Comment: @Withhelds actually I believe you have to cast the result column as a date since you can't convert the date column as it will again think you're referring to the actual field. see edit

Comment: @BrianDeMilia wow, it works! Thanks. I would like to ask a separate question which is related to this topic. Is it possible to change/design the date column in a specific format e.g. dd-mm-yyyy? Do I have to change system settings or it can be done via SQL design mode?

Comment: You can use SET DATEFORMAT - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Comment: @Withhelds: You can use a different format code in the Convert function, instead of 105 as used above, to change the display format.

Comment: Since you're using 2012, you can use the `FORMAT()` function to get any format you want, but if the format is available via `CONVERT()` that performs better than `FORMAT()`.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Thank you once again :)

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I have to use a dd-mm-yyyy format which I found online which is 105.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by the original date by using a table alias:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), [Date Depart], 105) AS [Date Depart]
FROM FLIGHT
ORDER BY FLIGHT.[Date Depart] DESC;
```